# Force merge and ignore «Already up to date.»

Tags: git

## Question

I have that history:

```
(C1) <---(C2)
     \
      \--(C3)
```

```
C1: empty commit.
C2: file1.txt
C3: file2.txt file3.txt
```

What I want:

```
(C1) <---(C2) <---(C4) <--(C5)
     \            /       /
      \--(C3) <--/-------/
```

```
C4: file1.txt file2.txt
C5: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

I tried to do it with `git merge`, but it writes to me "Already up to date.".
I have to use the commands `git cat-file`, `git mktree`, `git hash-object`, `git ls-tree` to do what I want. Is there an easier way?

## How to repeat

You can repeat yourself and check that it is not possible to do what I want (Ubuntu bash):

```sh
git init /tmp/force-merge
cd /tmp/force-merge/
git commit --allow-empty -m "empty commit."
echo 1 > file1.txt
git add file1.txt
git commit -m "file1.txt"
git checkout -b develop master~1
echo 2 > file2.txt
echo 3 > file3.txt
git add file2.txt file3.txt
git commit -m "file2.txt file3.txt"
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit develop
git rm -f file3.txt
git commit -m "file1.txt file2.txt"
git merge --no-commit develop
```

And you get the "Already up to date.". git log:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
*   59f6836 (HEAD -> master) file1.txt file2.txt
|\  
| * 884b550 (develop) file2.txt file3.txt
* | 5117ae6 file1.txt
|/  
* 94dfb3b empty commit.
```

Comment: `git merge` works with two branches: the source branch you mention in the `git merge` command line and the target branch that is always the current branch. What is the current branch when you run `git merge` and what is the command line you run? What commits are these branches point at?

Comment: @axiac I added repeat section

Comment: `C4` already has `C3`. There's no reason to merge again.

Comment: @colonel-thirty-two You are correct that `C4` already contains `C3`. However, I need to merge into multiple commits, not one commit.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge into multiple commits"? The changes in `C3` have already been applied, which is what `git merge` is telling you. Merging it "again" would do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @colonel-thirty-two I understand that merge is working correctly. I understand that `C4` overwrites `file3.txt` and so there is nothing to merge. However, I need to create `C4` with parents (`C2`, `C3`) and I need to create `C5` with parents (`C4`, `C3`) and set the changes to `C4` and `C5` manually.

Comment: @МихаилСидоренко Your proposed merges will not contain the files you want. If you explained the purpose of all this we could help find a better way. Do you just want one merge with file3.txt and one without? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recreates your start condition:

```
git init `mktemp -d`
cd $_
git commit --allow-empty -m C1
> file1.txt; git add .
git commit -m C2
git checkout -b topic :/C1
> file2.txt
> file3.txt; git add .
git commit -m C3
```

This creates C4:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit topic
git rm -f file3.txt
git commit -am C4
```

This creates C5:

```
git checkout :/C3 file3.txt
git reset --soft $(git commit-tree -p @ -p topic -m C5 `git write-tree`)
```

You could do it more cleanly by splitting C3 into separate commits and merging them,

```
git checkout -B topic :/C1
> file2.txt; git add .
git commit -m C3a
> file3.txt; git add .
git commit -m C3b
git checkout -B master :/C2
git merge :/C3a
git merge topic
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to get your proposed commits would be to make a new branch which removes file3 and then merge that.

```
C1 - C2 [master]
 \
  C3 [develop]

$ git co -b develop develop-no-file3

C1 - C2 [master]
 \
  C3 [develop]
     [develop-no-file3]

$ git rm file3
$ git commit

C1 - C2 [master]
 \
  C3 [develop]
    \
     C3A [develop-no-file3]
```

Now you can merge each as you like. Without knowing your purpose I can't say exactly how this should merge, but there doesn't seem much point in putting the merges on top of each other. Since `develop-no-file3` seems temporary, you could merge develop into master and then master into develop-no-file3.

```
$ git checkout develop-no-file3
$ git merge master

$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop

C1 --------- C2 ----- C3M [master]
 \             \    /
  C3  ----------*---
    \            \
     C3A -------- C3AM [develop-no-file3]
```

If you're doing this to produce different configurations of your software, maybe for different deployments, or maybe to remove develop-only code; Git is not a configuration management system. This should be handled another way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer really shows that it is possible to solve the `file1.txt` `file2.txt` `file3.txt` problem by creating multiple branches. However, the crux of the matter is how to create a commit specifying any parents without using a plumbing.

Comment: Second solution `file1.txt` `file2.txt` `file3.txt`: split the `C3` commit into `C3a`, `C3b` and merge these commits into `C2` one by one.

Comment: @МихаилСидоренко You're looking for a very specific solution that seems unnecessarily complicated, but I can't say for sure without knowing what problem you're trying to solve. Could you explain what you're solving? Rather than forcing Git to do it a certain way, it's often easier and better to alter the solution to fit Git.

Comment: I needed it to pull some functionality from a repository with an unrelated history. In this way, I do not appropriate authorship and preserve history.

Comment: I don't want to do merge in the original sense. I want to make a commit that has two parents so git knows where I'm copying the code from.

Comment: @МихаилСидоренко It's unclear to me how your approach would achieve that, or why a normal merge would not. I'd suggest asking a new question about that problem and seeing what answers you get.